# Django will not log until the root logger is used

Tags: python, django

I have set `logger` as is commonly suggested in each module:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I have a script that is being run through `./manage.py runscript` (using django-extensions). I'm not certain if the Django parts are relevant here.

I've found that none of the `logger` instances will log unless I add at least one `logging` call at the beginning of the script. For example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def run():
    logging.getLogger().level = logging.DEBUG
    # logging.info("START")
    logger.info("LOGGER START")
```

In this state, nothing logs in the whole system, but if I uncomment the `logging.info` line, then all modules log. Is there a requirement to "tickle" the root logger this way?

Comment: Don't get the part with uncommenting `logging.info`, but it's not enough just to add logger, you should also configure it (directly or with `settings.LOGGING`). Did you check default configuration? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-s-default-logging-configuration

Comment: I'm currently using it out of the box (basically startproject/startapp). But if I call `logging.info` at least once I don't need to configure it to get logging out, so I don't think it's the config per se.

Comment: Even if you comment line with root logger configuration? And what about `settings.DEBUG`? Is it set to False/True? You can share a minimal project and I take a look. Now I can't grasp what you expect and what you get.